# How to display multiple info windows for multiple MapView markers at a time?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-custom-view

I developed a sample application to show multiple markers on a `MapView`.
But I'm only able to display one info window for one marker at a time.
Is it possible to display multiple info windows for multiple markers at a time on a `MapView`?

Comment: Fixed grammar, clarified question. You should include the code of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the layout of your info window so that it looks like there is more than more.